# Trouble understanding mutation in rust in a simple for loop

Tags: rust

I'm having some trouble understanding what's going on in this simple example:

```
let mut my_vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

for v in &mut my_vec {
    *v += 1;
}
```

I would not expect this code to compile, as I'd assume that in the for loop, `v` would need to have been marked as `&mut` for it to work. But actually, marking it as `&mut v` makes the compilation fail. Why?!

My line of thought is as follows:

1. I want to increment `v` by 1, so `v` needs to be both a reference and mutable, hence the variable declaration in the for loop should be `&mut v`;
2. `my_vec` on the for-loop needs then to be marked as `mut`, as its values are going to be mutated, and as a reference, as we want to change the values of `my_vec`;
3. `my_vec` then also needs to be marked as `mut`, otherwise no mutations can be performed on it.

In other words, if I had not run the code through a compiler, this is what I would have come up with:

```
let mut my_vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

for &mut v in &mut my_vec {
    *v += 1;
}
```

Where am I failing?

Comment: cause you are doing a pattern matching and so v become an integer and not anymore a reference to integer. for `x` in `y`, `x` is a pattern matching.